# How to sign data with encrypted RSA private key (AES-256-CBC) in python

Tags: python, aes, rsa, pycrypto

Partial example of private_key (this variable is a string):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,hidden_text..

lots_of_hidden_text..

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

When I try to do the following:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
rsakey = RSA.importKey(private_key, passphrase=privkey_secret_string)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)
signature = signer.sign(data)
```

I'm getting value error on the importKey:

```
Error: ValueError: Unsupport PEM encryption algorithm.
```

I can see that RSA.importKey doesn't support AES-256-CBC, but i can't find any way to import this private key.

The only solution i've seen in order to create an AES signer is:

```
signer = AES.new(privkey_secret_string, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
```

But this doesn't use the private key

Comment: python [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) supports this. It can be read in with a function from the serialization module, [`load_pem_private_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either switch to PyCryptodome or decrypt the key with a system call to openssl prior to importing the key:

`echo PASSPHRASE | openssl rsa -in key.pem`

Comment: The openssl might work, is there any way to do it in python without system calls?
PyCryptodome doesn't support AES-256-CBC as well

Comment: Install pyopenssl and try `import OpenSSL; OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('privkey.pem', 'r').read(), passphrase=b'foobar')`